# React Button Sizing

Tags: reactjs

Before I add the href link to my button, the sizing looks proper like the one below. [This is the normal sized button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYDzL.png)

When I add the href: `{ <Button href={LINKS.twitter} external iconName="twitter"> FOLLOW US </Button> }`

[It turns the button into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OYCq.png)

I cant figure out why that is happening. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: can you please upload some of your code to GitHub or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) that can be a little more helpful to debug? some experts may require some info for your code eg. ```package.json``` etc.

Comment: What library are you using? `<Button>` seems to be coming from some kind of UI library/kit. Also, there is no reproducible example in your question, which makes it difficult to pinpoint where the issue is. See [mcve].